# Does Gibbering Gemstone only drop once?

Tags: diablo-iii

I had been hunting for Gibbering Gemstone for days on end!

And I grow tired and wary of it and decided to teach my fiancee how to do it when I took a couple hours break taking a shower and such.

I never know if she ever get the gemstone, because she might miss it or mistaken selling it! Because, after all, she didn't know what it is!

After that, I had been doing double the amount of hunting since then.

And the gemstone is no way near even the sign of dropping!

So it started to let me wondering if the following statement is true!?

> If the Gemstone is ever dropped, no matter if you ever claim it, it will **NEVER** drop again!!!

Comment: Where does that statement come from?

Comment: Why did you ask your fiance to play in your stead if you don't trust her to recognize the thing you're looking for when she sees it?  Did you not tell her you're farming for this rare gem that only drops from one unique huntress in a specific cave, so please keep it if you see it?  It's not like the game will explode if you take a break to go have a shower.

Comment: And its not like the cow level is A) anything new B) anything truly exciting C) of any use

Comment: @Steve-O Because I think she might be **WAY LUCKIER** than me!? Beginner's Luck!? XP   And I DID tell her to go to Caverns of Frost "ONLY"! And I just tell her to go to level 2 and kill EVERYTHING and PICK UP EVERYTHING! Because she had "never played the game", or maybe I should say, "almost never played ANY game"! So I think asking her to "Look for Chiltara and kill that xxx-xx-xxxxx and get everything she drops" might be way too much for her!  >3<

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't agree with C because that's a GREAT place to farm gems! So to me, it's of GREAT use! ^O^

Comment: @PiggyChu001 I'm assuming you handed the computer over to your fiance to play using the same account (since the gem in account-bound it wouldn't help you much for her to get one on her own account.)  If you're both playing on the same account, on the same computer then the game has **literally no way of knowing it's not you playing.**  The idea that she's "luckier" is pure superstition.  Seriously, you need to calm down.

Comment: @Steve-O Thanks! I'll keep trying it! BUT! You can't deny that "Luck" played a HUGE role in this beloved-yet-at-the-same-time-hated game!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That statement is not true for any drops in the game. Anything that drops can drop again, as long as you don't have it in your inventory, storage or, in case of collectibles, already added to your lore.

Comment: With an asterisk: There are a few drops that are guaranteed only the first time you kill a creature, such as the Skeleton King dropping Leoric's helm the first time he's killed if it's in campaign mode and you're level 15+.